# Error creating substrings from input file

Tags: c++, string, outofrangeexception

I'm trying to create substrings from my from each line of my input file.

I noticed that when i create a substring from substr(0,2) position zero it prints out correctly but if I start from anywhere greater than 0 it throws this error:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string

and Im also reading in lines in this format 40AF FF A9

```
int main() 
{
  string STRING;
  ifstream infile;
  infile.open("test-file.txt");
  while(!infile.eof())
  {
     getline(infile, STRING);
     string tag = STRING.substr(2,2);
     cout << tag << endl;
  }
  return 0;
```

Comment: Can we see a chunk of the test-file.txt? (not just the format)  Add it to the question, not a comment, pls.

Comment: You should always check the size of the string before performing a substring operation. What if, for example, you have a blank line?

Comment: You check before reading instead of after reading! Use `while (std::getline(infile, STRING))`. Also, you need to have at least 4 character in the string for your `STRING.substr(2, 2)` to succeed. You should verify that this is the case (with your current setup you'll get undefined behavior after the last line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `substr`() method is defined as follows, in the C++ standard:

> 21.4.7.8 basic_string::substr     [string::substr]
>
> basic_string
>
> ```
>  substr(size_type pos = 0, size_type n = npos) const;
>
>  1 Requires: pos <= size()
>
>  2 Throws: out_of_range if pos > size().
> ```

So, the `pos` parameter, the first parameter to the `substr`() method, must be less than or equal to `size`(), the size of the `std::basic_string` class instance.

You are passing "2" for the "pos" parameter, so this method will throw an exception if the length of your string is less than 2 characters.

If your code reads an empty line from the file, the string's `size`() will be less than two, and your code will throw an exception.